# pytest get runtime function test variable

Tags: python, pytest

I am using the plugin repeat and need to extract the current test at runtime (to be used for a logger). I assume I shall access the: dummy.py::test_dummy[1-4]

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def initial_setup():
    print(f'\n\n<<< setup >>>')
    counter_not_working = 0
    yield counter_not_working
    print('\n<<< teardown >>>')

@pytest.mark.repeat(int(os.getenv("repeat", "4")))
def test_dummy(initial_setup):

    # Alt.1
    counter_not_working = initial_setup
    counter_not_working = + 1
    print(f'\nTo be used for a logger..., test no: {counter_not_working}???')

    # Alt.2
    counter_get_from_pytest = 0  # ???
    print(f'To be used for a logger..., test no: {counter_get_from_pytest}???')
    pass
```

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0 -- xxx/xxx
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /xxx/, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: repeat-0.8.0
collecting ... collected 4 items

**dummy.py::test_dummy[1-4]**

<<< setup >>>
PASSED                                         [ 25%]
To be used for a logger..., test no: 1???
To be used for a logger..., test no: 0???

dummy.py::test_dummy[2-4] PASSED                                         [ 50%]
To be used for a logger..., test no: 1???
To be used for a logger..., test no: 0???

dummy.py::test_dummy[3-4] PASSED                                         [ 75%]
To be used for a logger..., test no: 1???
To be used for a logger..., test no: 0???

dummy.py::test_dummy[4-4] PASSED                                         [100%]
To be used for a logger..., test no: 1???
To be used for a logger..., test no: 0???

<<< teardown >>>

=========================== 4 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

I found i myself:

def test_dummy(initial_setup, **request**):
    no_of_tests = str(**request.node**)
    print(type(no_of_tests))